# How do I add a UIView on top of a MKAnnotationView and then display it on a MKMapView?

Tags: ios

My goal is to have custom pins on a `MKMapView`. I have a `UIView` with a label on it and I'd like to use it for the custom pins. I've implemented the `viewForAnnotation` method to display my `UIView` on the map.

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier("")
    } else {
        let annotationView = MKAnnotationView()
        annotationView.canShowCallout = false
        annotationView.addSubview(myView) // myView is the regular UIView
        return annotationView
    }
}
```

The pins are now displayed, but they're placed randomly on the map. I think this is because I have to create a `MKAnnotation` and assign coordinates to it. How do I add a `UIView` to a `MKAnnotationView` and then display it on a `MKMapView`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You left out a tiny but key step: in every case, you must assign the incoming annotation to the annotation view's `annotation` property.

Comment: Thanks Matt! I've just added `annotationView.annotation = annotation`. Though, how do I say: "Hey, you need to put your annotation here". How do I give the `MKAnnotation` the coordinates it needs to be placed on the map on a certain location? I see people are subclassing the `MKAnnotation`. Thanks!!

Comment: "How do I give the MKAnnotation the coordinates it needs" It already has them, because you assigned the `coordinate` when you created the MKAnnotation in the first place. But you didn't show that code, so that would be a different question.